# File is getting corrupted while using outputstream to upload

Tags: java, excel, file-upload, outputstream, aspose

Every time when I upload a excel with partial data, the uploaded file get corrupt and I am unable to use this uploaded file in aspose workbook (in some cases it works too, i don't know why). And even then I open this while, excel displays the corrupted file messaage. Here, is the snippet

```
InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();


OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("path_to_xlsFile.xls");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
       bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
bos.flush();
bos.close();
os.close();
stream.close();
```

The error that I get while open the workbook through aspose library, for the same uploaded file is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The FAT in the structured storage document seems to be corrupted.
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.open(Unknown Source)
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The structured storage seems to be corrupt.
at com.aspose.cells.mm.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.c(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.open(Unknown Source)
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: length
at com.aspose.cells.b.a.d.h.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.c(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.open(Unknown Source)
```

### Edit

If I use  file.transferTo(outputFile), then also for few files I get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The FAT in the structured storage document seems to be corrupted.
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.b(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.py.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.open(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: are the file sizes equal?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No they are different sized. You meant the files I am uploading, their sizes? right?

Comment: You should use Apache POI.

Comment: @Amit thanks for suggestion, but I don't really have option but to use this only

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seem to get some part of data from the template XLS file which might negate/deteriorate the overall Excel file format specifications or standards. So, the extracted file in bytes array (or stream) would not follow MS Excel file format structure or rules. In short the file would be corrupted and MS Excel too displays error messages when opening the file into it as you mentioned. This may not be an issue with Aspose.Cells APIs. Could you simply try the following sample code segments (any of the two) if it works fine:
e.g
Sample code:

```
1)
Path path = Paths.get("path_to_xlsFile.xls"); 
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(path)); 

Workbook workbook = new Workbook(stream); 
.........

2)
String testFileTemplate = "path_to_xlsFile.xls"; 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(testFileTemplate)); 
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(fis);
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I have to save it too, and even with  workbook.save(outputstream, SaveFormat.EXCEL_97_TO_2003), I am unable to save it as the files which were getting corrupted, workbook.save is throwing an exception at it.

Comment: Workbook workbook = new Workbook(fis);  this is also giving java.lang.IllegalStateException: The FAT in the structured storage document.... this exception

Comment: I think your file is not a valid Excel file or corrupted, so you won't be able to open the file by both MS Excel and Aspose.Cells APIs. If you still are able to open the file via MS Excel and not by Aspose.Cells, kindly share the file (you may upload the file to some file sharing service (e.g dropbox) and paste the download link), we will check it soon.